# When should the fuel pump be on in a Cessna 152?

Tags: fuel-systems, cessna-152

I am a new student and just need help understanding the fuel pump system. For a Cessna 152, in which scenario would I have the fuel pump on ?

Start ?
After Start ?
Before Take-Off ?
After Take-Off ?
Changing tank selection ?
Stalls/Spins ?
Approach and Landing ?
After Landing ?

Comment: I've never seen a 152 with a manually operated fuel pump, it's a gravity fed system with an enginne driven pump - you dont switch it on or off as such

Comment: related (or duplicate if you remove the 152 detail): https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21993/when-is-a-fuel-pump-needed-on-ga-aircraft